# Flask based application : CloudFlare Gateway Timeout error

Tags: python, flask

Because the model prediction in my ML application takes 150 seconds to respond, I received gateway Timeout error. Is there a method to render something while the model prediction process running to avoid the aforementioned problem.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want your API endpoint to kick off a background task that computes the model if it takes >150seconds to finish. You could also have another endpoint that gets the status of this job which your frontend can poll and then receive results from when the job is finished.

This is just one strategy that you can use, but ultimately you don't want the model prediction to be happening in the request itself - 150 seconds is a very generous timeout and something like 30 or 60 seconds is much more common, anything that will take that long to compute should be done in the background.